# Puppetserver cannot start

Tags: puppet, jruby

Today i faced with issue that puppetserver suddenly become dead.

I already tried to add -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/puppet/tmp to JAVA_ARGS in /etc/default/puppetserver

this new tmp folder have 1777 perms and puppet as owner.

There is no more helpful result during google =(
Please help where to dig ?

Full log here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h-Tmqg9YJ5VLWe4OhvftNzQHOxkzfesF/view?usp=sharing

```
2022-10-20T18:41:05.668Z INFO  [main] [o.e.j.u.log] Logging initialized @14500ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2022-10-20T18:41:07.894Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.s.s.scheduler-service] Initializing Scheduler Service
2022-10-20T18:41:08.005Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory] Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2022-10-20T18:41:08.069Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.c.SchedulerSignalerImpl] Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2022-10-20T18:41:08.069Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.c.QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
2022-10-20T18:41:08.070Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.s.RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.
2022-10-20T18:41:08.078Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.c.QuartzScheduler] Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'c709d36f-47d9-48e3-a618-a56f2f00e737' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

2022-10-20T18:41:08.078Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'c709d36f-47d9-48e3-a618-a56f2f00e737' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2022-10-20T18:41:08.078Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
2022-10-20T18:41:08.078Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.c.QuartzScheduler] Scheduler c709d36f-47d9-48e3-a618-a56f2f00e737_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2022-10-20T18:41:08.087Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.s.w.jetty9-service] Initializing web server(s).
2022-10-20T18:41:08.272Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.s.s.status-service] Registering status callback function for service 'puppet-profiler', version 7.9.2
2022-10-20T18:41:08.282Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.s.j.jruby-puppet-service] Initializing the JRuby service
2022-10-20T18:41:08.359Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.s.j.jruby-pool-manager-service] Initializing the JRuby service
2022-10-20T18:41:08.396Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.s.j.jruby-puppet-service] JRuby version info: jruby 9.3.4.0 (2.6.8) 2022-03-23 eff48c1ebf OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.342-b07 on 1.8.0_342-8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04-b07 +jit [x86_64-linux]
2022-10-20T18:41:08.466Z INFO  [clojure-agent-send-pool-0] [p.s.j.i.jruby-internal] Creating JRubyInstance with id 1.
2022-10-20T18:41:08.487Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.s.s.status-service] Registering status callback function for service 'jruby-metrics', version 7.9.2
2022-10-20T18:41:08.509Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.s.v.versioned-code-service] No code-id-command set for versioned-code-service. Code-id will be nil.
2022-10-20T18:41:08.515Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.s.v.versioned-code-service] No code-content-command set for versioned-code-service. Attempting to fetch code content will fail.
2022-10-20T18:41:08.538Z INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.s.m.jolokia] Metrics access control using trapperkeeper-authorization is enabled.
2022-10-20T18:41:20.640Z ERROR [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.internal] Error during service init!!!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to borrow JRubyInstance from pool
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34345$borrow_from_pool_BANG__STAR___34350$fn__34351.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:313)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34345$borrow_from_pool_BANG__STAR___34350.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:300)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34392$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__34397$fn__34398.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:348)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34392$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__34397.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:337)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__35156.invokeStatic(instance_pool.clj:48)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__35156.invoke(instance_pool.clj:10)
    at puppetlabs.services.protocols.jruby_pool$fn__34946$G__34894__34953.invoke(jruby_pool.clj:3)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.jruby_core$fn__36070$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__36075$fn__36076.invoke(jruby_core.clj:222)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.jruby_core$fn__36070$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__36075.invoke(jruby_core.clj:209)
    at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_core$fn__44216$get_puppet_config__44221$fn__44222$fn__44223.invoke(puppet_server_config_core.clj:107)
    at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_core$fn__44216$get_puppet_config__44221$fn__44222.invoke(puppet_server_config_core.clj:107)
    at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_core$fn__44216$get_puppet_config__44221.invoke(puppet_server_config_core.clj:102)
    at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_service$reify__44251$service_fnk__5324__auto___positional$reify__44262.init(puppet_server_config_service.clj:25)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services$fn__5148$G__5140__5151.invoke(services.clj:9)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services$fn__5148$G__5139__5155.invoke(services.clj:9)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14616$run_lifecycle_fn_BANG___14623$fn__14624.invoke(internal.clj:196)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14616$run_lifecycle_fn_BANG___14623.invoke(internal.clj:179)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14645$run_lifecycle_fns__14650$fn__14651.invoke(internal.clj:229)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14645$run_lifecycle_fns__14650.invoke(internal.clj:206)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15283$build_app_STAR___15292$fn$reify__15304.init(internal.clj:602)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15331$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___15338$fn__15339$fn__15341.invoke(internal.clj:630)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15331$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___15338$fn__15339.invoke(internal.clj:629)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15331$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___15338.invoke(internal.clj:623)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__5910.invoke(core.clj:2647)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14690$initialize_lifecycle_worker__14701$fn__14702$fn__14865$state_machine__11925__auto____14890$fn__14893.invoke(internal.clj:249)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14690$initialize_lifecycle_worker__14701$fn__14702$fn__14865$state_machine__11925__auto____14890.invoke(internal.clj:249)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:978)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:977)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:982)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:980)
    at clojure.core.async$ioc_alts_BANG_$fn__12154.invoke(async.clj:421)
    at clojure.core.async$do_alts$fn__12093$fn__12096.invoke(async.clj:288)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel$fn__6766$fn__6767.invoke(channels.clj:99)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.concurrent$counted_thread_factory$reify__6669$fn__6670.invoke(concurrent.clj:29)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (LoadError) load error: psych -- java.lang.RuntimeException: BUG: we can not copy embedded jar to temp directory
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:131)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1296)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1289)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:167)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:102)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby.jruby_puppet_core$fn__36371$get_initialize_pool_instance_fn__36376$fn__36377$fn__36378.invoke(jruby_puppet_core.clj:118)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34145$create_pool_instance_BANG___34154$fn__34157.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:256)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34145$create_pool_instance_BANG___34154.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:225)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34563$add_instance__34568$fn__34572.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:52)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34563$add_instance__34568.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:47)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34590$prime_pool_BANG___34595$fn__34599.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:76)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34590$prime_pool_BANG___34595.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:61)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__35152$fn__35153.invoke(instance_pool.clj:16)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invokeStatic(internal.clj:403)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invoke(internal.clj:378)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invokeStatic(internal.clj:388)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invoke(internal.clj:378)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15134$shutdown_service__15139$fn$reify__15141$service_fnk__5324__auto___positional$reify__15146.shutdown_on_error(internal.clj:448)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15081$G__15060__15089.invoke(internal.clj:411)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15081$G__15059__15098.invoke(internal.clj:411)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__5908.invoke(core.clj:2642)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__5908.invoke(core.clj:2641)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34537$send_agent__34542$fn__34543$agent_fn__34544.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:41)
    at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__5823.invoke(core.clj:2050)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.doRun(Agent.java:114)
    at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.run(Agent.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.LoadError: (LoadError) load error: psych -- java.lang.RuntimeException: BUG: we can not copy embedded jar to temp directory
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
    at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/psych_jars.rb:2)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
    at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/psych.rb:5)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
    at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/yaml.rb:4)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/network/format_handler.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require_relative(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045)
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/network/format_support.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require_relative(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045)
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/tag_set.rb:2)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require_relative(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045)
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/tagging.rb:2)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require_relative(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045)
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/log.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require_relative(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045)
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/logging.rb:2)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require_relative(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045)
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:795)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require_relative(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045)
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:16)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
    at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
    at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server/master.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
    at RUBY.<main>(<script>:1)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: BUG: we can not copy embedded jar to temp directory
```

Comment: as update

there was no ruby or java updates today
Only: 
Upgrade: git-man:amd64
Upgrade: perl-base:amd64
Upgrade: sosreport:amd64
Upgrade: libksba8:amd64

Comment: i was able to start server but now when im trying to run puppet agent -t on puppet server im getting:

Comment: Connection to https://puppet:8140/puppet/v3 failed, trying next route: Request to https://puppet:8140/puppet/v3 failed after 18.589 seconds: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "puppet" port 8140)

Comment: Questions about writing Puppet manifests, plugins, templates, and the like are on topic here on SO.  Not so much questions about setting up and running the Puppet client and server.  Questions of the latter type, such as this one, are better suited for [Server Fault SE](https://serverfault.com/).